# Send data from state to component in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I want to search on the map depending by coordinates from input. I can't figure out why the map doesn't react to my request.

```js
  

function App  ()  {

  let [state, setState] = React.useState([55.75, 37.57]);
    function search(e) {
        const val = e.target.value;
        console.log(e.target)
        setState([val]);
    }

    function searchSubmit(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        console.log(state)
    }


        return (
            <YMaps>
                <div className="App">
                    <form onSubmit={searchSubmit}>
                        <input value={state} type="text" onChange={search}/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    </form>
                    <Map defaultState={{center: {state}, zoom: 9}}/>
                </div>
            </YMaps>

        );
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
      document.getElementById('container')
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-yandex-maps/dist/production/react-yandex-maps.umd.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

When i change `<Map defaultState={{center: {state}, zoom: 9}}/>` to `<Map defaultState={{ center: [55.75, 37.57], zoom: 9 }} />` it works (the last variant is from documentation). What could be the problem?

Comment: I think you have extra curly braces, it should just be `<Map defaultState={{center: state, zoom: 9}}/>`

Comment: @Jayce444, i want to add dynamic the value for the map, could you help me with this? The component works, but i can't understand why the map is not changing when i try to add different coordinates from my input. I wrote it on an online editor because on this site the editor throw errors with map package even i installed it.   https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-km14w3

Comment: Is this a new question? If so, please open a new one with all the relevant info, code, specific errors, things you've tried etc.. If this is the same question, then there shouldn't be an answer marked as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Map defaultState={{ center: [55.75, 37.57], zoom: 9 }} />
```

Here the center key is expecting data type to be array of data.

Please ensure when you are assigning state to center its data format is array and not object. Since you have enclosed state in {} its taking it as object.

try

```
<Map defaultState={{center: state, zoom: 9}}/>
```

Comment: i want to add dynamic the value for the map, could you help me with this? The component works, but i can't understand why the map is not changing when i try to add different coordinates from my input. I wrote it on a online editor because on this site the editor throw errors with map package even i installed it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-km14w3

Comment: See your answer is in your question. You have managed to do it statically. Now instead of passing [55,55] hardcoded think how does this value be updated on some event. check this if you can understand: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ysuymm?file=index.js

Comment: but anyway i can't change the location clicking the button. Can you take a look? and why i can change the location only statically in ` let [btn, setBtn] = useState([152.75, 37.57]); `?

Answer (score 1):

Remove curly brackets

```
<Map defaultState={{center: state, zoom: 9}}/>
```